# How do I do a LIKE search with an @ in the search in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

[I don't see @ as a special character in the MySQL list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) but my `SELECT` with a `LIKE` and an `@` gives me an empty result. I would like to do something like

```
SELECT email from myTable WHERE email LIKE '%@domain.com'
```

Comment: [@ is not a special character with regards to the LIKE operator in MySQL](http://rextester.com/JCGG49620).  Can you make your question reproducible?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data.  I don't see any problem just from what you told us.

Comment: Please post sample email from your DB "as-is". Using copy-paste. Skip part before `@`.

Comment: It actually affects the LIKE value. In any case it appears as though it does need to be escaped, even if it's not listed as a character that needs escaping. Thank you for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `ESCAPE` clause (wild guess):

```
SELECT email 
from myTable 
WHERE email LIKE '%!@domain.com' ESCAPE '!';
```

---

Another option is to trim your email (probably some white characters):

```
SELECT email 
from myTable 
WHERE TRIM(email) LIKE '%@domain.com';
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For example `'xyz@domain.com    '` Then you don't get a match.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier You could try:`'%someValue@domain%'`. I suspect that your strings are `NULL-terminated`.

Comment: It's not an issue with null terminated, I just put a comment too soon :(